# Is it possible to stop a subversion checkin if the teamcity build is broken?

Tags: svn, teamcity

We have a large distributed team some of which continually check in without updating first and (worse!) check in when the teamcity build is red.

Is it possible to set subversion to check a teamcity build status before allowing people to check in new work?

I realise this is almost certainly a horrible thing to do and team education and complacence would be better...

Comment: I'm glad I don't work on your codebase :-s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a svn pre-commit hook which will use the TeamCity API to see if the build is broken, and if so, stop the commits.

Answer (score 2):

Teamcity offers a feature called "[pre-tested commit](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/features/delayed_commit.html)", maybe this would help you?